# Cant Connect to MySQL over network

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of setting up a MySQL server. I set up the server as localhost on port 3306. However I want to be able to access this server over the network. The server has a static IP address. How can I change it from localhost to the static IP address?

I already did this suggestion I found online, and it didn't work:

```
 mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 

 mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I try to access it from the server or another PC, I get this error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at XXXXXX:3306 with user root
HOST 'XXXXXXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the `GRANT` statement you've already listed above, you also need this one to connect from somewhere other than `localhost`

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';
```

In MySQL land `user@somehost` is, in practice, a different user than `user@some-other-host`.